# Prove $a=b$ if $4p^{2a}+4p^b+1$ is a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, square-numbers

> Let $p$ be an odd prime, and $a$, $b$ be two positive integers such that $2a>b$. If $4p^{2a}+4p^b+1$ is a perfect square, prove that $a=b$.

If $b<a$, then $(2p^a)^2<4p^{2a}+4p^b+1<(2p^a+1)^2$, which is contradictory. So $b\ge a$. If we write $4p^{2a}+4p^b+1=m^2$, then $(m+1)(m-1)=4p^b(p^{2a-b}+1)$. Since $(m+1,m-1)\le2$, then exactly one of $m+1$ and $m-1$ is divisible by $p^b$.

Then I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I continue with your solution. Since $4p^2a+4p^b+1$ is odd, then $m^2$ is odd implies m is odd. So $gcd(m+1,m-1) = 2$. Hence $4 \mid (m+1)(m-1)$ So we let $\frac{m+1}{2} = s$ and $\frac{m-1}{2} = s-1$
We have $s(s-1) = p^b(p^{2a - b} + 1)$ Since $(p^b, p^{2a - b} + 1) = 1$ and similar for $(s,s-1)$ = 1, then $$\\$$ Case 1: $p^b$ = $s-1$ and $p^{2a - b} + 1 = s$ $$\\$$Case 2: $p^b = s$ and $p^2a-b + 1 = s - 1$
$$\\$$ Case 1 implies a = b $$\\$$
For case 2 we have $p^b = p^{2a-b} + 2$, using the fact that $b\ge a$ we get $p^{2a-b}(p^{2b-2a} - 1) = 2$, $b = a$ leads contradiction so $b > a$, then $p^{2a-b} $ and $ p^{2b-2a} \ge 3$, contradiction because $p^{2a-b}(p^{2b-2a} - 1) = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument for the case $b < a$ is fine.

Next suppose $b > a$.

From $b > a$, we get $b\ge 2$, hence
$$
p^b\ge 3^b=(2+1)^b > 2^b+b2^{b-1} > 2^b+2
$$
so $p^b-1 > 2^b+1$, an inequality to be used later.

As you observed, exactly one of $m+1,m-1$ is divisible by $p^b$.

Let $x$ denote the one of $m+1,m-1$ which is divisible by $p^b$, and let $y$ denote the other one.

Since $m$ is odd, $x,y$ are both even.

It follows that $x$ is divisible by $2p^b$.

Then $x\ge 2p^b$, hence from the equality
$$
xy=(2p^b)\bigl(2(p^{2a-b}+1)\bigr)\qquad\qquad
$$
we get
\begin{align*}
y\le\;&2(2^{2a-b}+1)
\\[4pt]
 <\;&
2(2^b+1)\qquad\bigl(\text{since $b > a$}\bigr)
\\[4pt]
 <\;&
2(p^b-1)
\\[4pt]
=\;&
2p^b-2
\\[4pt]
\le\;&
x-2
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so $y < x-2$, contradiction.

Answer (score -2):

$4p^{2a} + 4p^b + 1$ is a perfect square.

$(2p^a)^2 + 2(2p^b) + 1 = (2p^a +1)^2$

$2(2p^b) = 2(2p^a)$

$a = b$